# Do I need to use virtualenv with Vagrant?

Tags: python, django, virtual-machine, virtualenv, vagrant

I was used VirtualBox manual setups with virtualenvs inside them to run Django projects on my local machine. Recently I discovered Vagrant and decided to switch to it, because it seems very easy and useful. 
But I can not figure - do I need still use virtualenv Vagrant VM, is it encouraged practice or forbidden?

Comment: if you do use virtualenv on vagrant, watch out for slowness when the virtualenv is in a vagrant shared directory. more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972471/python-virtualenv-is-very-slow/27844226#27844226

Comment: I don't know why so many people answer this question with "don't use virtualenv but create virtualenv-usable packages", creating a python package is an independent process and you can still `pip install` packages even if you are not in a virtualenv. So of course every python software should support setuptools.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you run one vagrant VM per project, then there is no direct reason to use virtualenv.

If other contributors do not use vagrant, but do use virtualenv, then you might want to use it and support it to make their lives easier.

Comment: 'one vagrant VM per project' - you mean that Vagrants works in such way that if I add one box to it, and use it in many projects - they will not use individual vdi files, they will share same operating system and their setups on it?

Comment: No, you can use one box -- a box is just a template for a VM. I just mean that if multiple projects use the same directory and that directory is a vagrant environment, then the projects aren't isolated from each other.

Answer (score 31):

As [Devin stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18271644/41747), it is not necessary to use `virtualenv` when you deploy to a vagrant machine as long as you are the sole user of the machine.  However, I would still enable the use of a `virtualenv`, *setup.py*, etc. even if you do not use it for development or deployment.

In my (not so) humble opinion, any Python project should:

1. Include a *.cvsignore*, *.gitignore*, *.hgignore*, ... file that ignores the common Python intermediate files as well as `virtualenv` directories.
2. A *requirements.txt* file that lists the required packages in a [*pip*-compliant](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#requirements-files) format
3. Include a *Makefile* with the following targets:

   - **environment**: create the virtual environment using `virtualenv` or `pyvenv`
   - **requirements**: install required packages using `pip` and the *requirements.txt* file
   - **develop**: run `setup.py develop` using the virtual environment
   - **test**: run `setup.py test`
   - **clean**: remove intermediate files, coverage reports, etc.
   - **maintainer-clean**: remove the virtual environment

   The idea is to keep the *Makefile* as simple as possible.  The dependencies should be set up so that you can clone the repository (or extract the source tarball) and run `make test`.  It should create a virtual environment, install the requirements, and run the unit tests.

You can also include a *Vagrantfile* and a **vagrant** target in the Makefile that runs *vagrant up*.  Add a `vagrant destroy` to the **maintainer-clean** target while you are at it.

This makes your project usable by anyone that is using vagrant or developing without it.  If (when) you need to use deploy alongside another project in a vagrant or physical environment, including a clean *setup.py* and a *Vagrantfile* that describes your minimal environment makes it simple to install into a virtual environment or a shared vagrant machine.

Comment: Could you give some example of such project?

Answer (score 9):

Virtualenv and other forms of isolation (Docker, dedicated VM, ...) are not necessarily mutually exclusive. Using virtualenv is still a good idea, even in an isolated environment, to shield the virtual system Python from your project packages. *nix systems use plethora of Python based utilities dependent on specific versions of packages being available in system Python and you don't want to mess with these.

Mind that virtualenv can still only go as far as pure Python packages and doesn't solve the situation with native extensions that will still mix with the system.

Comment: I appreciated this answer more after going the route of the selected answer and dealing with weird package import issues. After wasting hours, I came back to use virtual environment; so I strongly recommend it. It saves you some piece of mind (unless you are a python/linux pro and want to deal with it).