# Python virtualenv is very slow

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 with Python 2.7.3 and I've just ported a Django 1.5.4 site to virtualenv 1.7.1.2.

However, I've noticed that Python commands are much slower when they are run from an active virtualenv than when using the system's Python installation. E.g. runnig `python manage.py validate` with system's Python lasts ~1s while the same command run inside a virtualenv environment lasts ~4s. Is this normal? Am I missing something? Will I have efficiency issues when deploying this site with Apache + virtualenv?

Note: When the local Django development server is running I haven't noticed efficiency issues while using the site. It seems to only affect python commands run from shell inside a virtualenv... Is this true?

**Update1:**

Here you have an example of the times I'm actually getting:

```
enric@developer:~/Documentos/workspace/EurekaStart$ time python manage.py validate
0 errors found

real    0m1.049s
user    0m0.648s
sys     0m0.120s
enric@developer:~/Documentos/workspace/EurekaStart$ source env/bin/activate
(env)enric@developer:~/Documentos/workspace/EurekaStart$ time python manage.py validate
0 errors found

real    0m5.261s
user    0m0.968s
sys     0m1.032s
```

**Update 2:**

I've done further testing and updated virtualenv to the latest version 1.10.1 and I've noticed that the times times have improved, but just a litte (between 0.5s and 1s). I have also tried to create the env with the `--system-site-packages` flag and time is much better, but still slower than using system's default Python. Here are the times:

Using `env` created without using `system-site-packages`:

```
(env)enric@developer:~/Documentos/workspace/EurekaStart$ time python manage.py validate
0 errors found

real    0m4.648s
user    0m1.008s
sys     0m0.824s
```

Using `env2` created using `system-site-packages`:

```
(env2)enric@developer:~/Documentos/workspace/EurekaStart$ time python manage.py validate
0 errors found

real    0m1.921s
user    0m0.760s
sys     0m0.312s
```

Just to note, normal execution without ANY env lasts 1s (as stated in update1).

---

I've just created the same virtualenv with exactly the same libs installed inside from a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 (live CD) and everything works as expected! It even ran faster on this new machine: 0.6s instead of 1.0 in my machine.

One interesting point to note: If I use the virtualenv created from the fresh Ubuntu in my real machine it runs as fast as executing the command without virtualenv, which is what is actually expected. But, if I use the virtualenvs created from this machine, then they run very slow.

So, I guess that the libs installed in the system really influence on how a virtualenv is created.

Now, the question would be... **Is there any way to purge my Ubuntu installation to be able to create efficient virtualenvs**? Is there any known lib that may cause this issue? (There aren't broken packages in the system, as I've already checked this).

Comment: That is NOT normal.  Can you run `time python manage.py SOMECOMMAND` (replacing SOMECOMMAND with a command that will not destroy your system) inside and outside the venv?  perception is killer and so is conformation bias, so real numbers are a better tool to work with.

Comment: @Tritium21 Thanks for your comment, I've just included the times.

Comment: what is the exact command used to create the venv?  did you specify a python?

Comment: @Tritium21 I used the command `virtualenv env` as in this version `--no-site-packages` is deprecated

Comment: does your code have any optional dependencies (even in its libraries) that are in your system wide environment, that are not in your venv?  Also, have you set any environment variables pertaining to python (PYTHONPATH and the like; virtualenv does not touch pythonpath)

Comment: A bit heavy handed, but try `strace -o strace.log -tt python manage.py validate` for each virtualenv and do some rough comparison of the resulting logs.  Perhaps one is doing a lot more `stat` calls while searching for imports.

Comment: From what I actually experienced, all the dependencies in my code that were not installed in the venv but present in the system caused a crash (which is actually the expected behaviour). I haven't set any environment variables pertaining to python.

Comment: Try installing all the dependencies (run outside the venv `python -v YOUR COMMAND` to see what is actually getting imported, then make sure they are available inside the venv) and see if that helps.  Sometimes a piece of code will try importing a fast version of a module, then fall back to a slow version, or something they implemented themselves.

Comment: @AustinPhillips this command returns a HUGE output. Do you want me to post it to somewhere else like pastebin?

Comment: @Caumons It's probably too much for others to digest.  You could do some of your own analysis on the logs to look for possible causes. eg Are there any system calls taking a long time in one of the venvs, are the logs roughly the same length etc?

Comment: @Tritium21 I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean... What do I have to install? And which command do I have to run? :S

Comment: what i mean, is run your manage.py outside the venv where it works, with the -v flag set.  that will print a TON of information to your screen - this is the module import log.  If you look through that you can see what packages are being imported, and make sure they are in the venv (if they are not in the stdlib, of course).  The reason for asking you to do this is some modules can `try: import somemodule; except ImportError: do_something_else_thats_slower()` and this eliminates that as a possible cause.

Comment: @AustinPhillips I can't even open the file using `gedit` (too big) and I'm afraid this is too low level for me... :(

Comment: @Tritium21 Ok, know I understand what you mean, but... Which command should I execute with `-v` in order to see this imports log?

Comment: `runserver` is not a bad option.  that should tax the bulk of your application's code.  `validate` should touch anything it misses.   Edit: `python -v manage.py runserver`

Comment: @Tritium21 The output is too big that I'm trying to redirect output to a file like `python -v manage.py runserver > output.txt` but it only ouptputs the `runserver` output. I think this is one of the biggest issues I've faced and I've no idea on how to continue with virtualenv. I'm considering reverting this job...

Comment: If it means eating this week or not, then i would advise forgetting vens for this project and just working through.  but to get the output to a file, use the "&>" redirecter: `python -v manage.py runserver &> output.txt`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37911/discussion-between-caumons-and-tritium21)

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same versions of the packages? `pip freeze`...

Comment: @Wolph When using the `--system-site-packages`, I undestand that the environment uses the system's Python libs, so I don't get why it is still slower than normal execution

Comment: @Wolph, Tritium21, AustinPhillips: I've found a workaround to get it working and posted an answer. I think this is an interesting issue... You can comment on it if you want.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a phantom issue, caused by virtualisation, not virtualenv.

Comment: What filesystem are you using? Is your virtualenv using the same filesystem type on the same hardware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the efficiency issues with virtualenv may be caused by the type of HDD partition it is allocated. In my case, running virtualenv from a NTFS partition causes it to be really slow. However, running a virtualenv with exactly the same libs from an Ext4 partition works as expected.

Comment: I'm using virtualenv inside vagrant on a Ext4 partition and I had the same problem. with virtualenv: real 0m3.852s, without: real 0m0.030s

Comment: You think you have it bad? 
real 7m10.014s
user 0m0.904s
sys 0m13.809s

Comment: @DylanMadisetti it's impressive that you found out it takes 7 min; I'd have assumed after just 15s that it's never going to be imported, and terminated it...

Answer (score 13):

This applies primarily to Vagrant-powered virtualenvs, but I ran into the same problem: *extremely slow manage.py / django-admin.py* (~ 10-15s. for django-admin.py version).

I found the culprit to be **vagrant/virtualbox**, and specifically **generating the virtualenv on a shared folder**.

Regenerating the virtualenv on a non-shared folder (like *~/.envs*) solved the problem for me.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: At the time I faced the issue I didn't use vagrant. So, there seem to be several cases where virtualenv runs slowly.

Comment: Great! This is the problem with using virtualenvs on ``vagrant``: Don't create them in shared folders !!!